# Cross compiling 64bit to 32bit

Tags: cross-compilation, 64-bit

Is there a means of compiling applications on 64bit RaspbianOS to run on 32bit Raspbian? I'm trying to compile Google Test on a 32bit Pi at the moment and I'm not getting very far. So I'm guessing an 8Gb 64bit machine would compile it sometime before the end of the universe.

Comment: Are you running out of memory during compile? Otherwise, just increasing the memory (but otherwise the same hardware) won't change much, I suppose. Using a linux-based PC (or VM) would probably help more. Depends on how the build is configured for that particular application, but it is generally possible to cross-compile from X86/X64 to Arm.

Comment: It brings the Pi to an absolute grinding halt. So I suspect a memory issue. I've just compiled on my Pi4 with no problem.

Comment: Then I guess you need to check with the docs of that application whether they support cross-compilling.

Comment: You'll need an appropriate cross-compiler...which also means all the 32-bit libs you need to link.  Might be easier if you booted a 32-bit OS on the Pi 4 and did it that way, since the issue is almost certainly not 32-bit vs. 64 bit, it's an 8gb Pi 4 vs. whatever the other one is.  Just take the card out of the one and put it in the other.

Comment: Note: A 8GB Pi4 will only show <4GB ram in 32bit mode. On the other hand all pointers are half the size so the memory required for gcc is noticeable less. If it compiles 64bit code with 8GB then it probably will manage 32bit code with 4GB too.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow not quite true a single process cannot physically address more than 4gb but virtual memory can enable a much larger space to be utilised, though I’m not sure if the arm architecture supports such.

Comment: @goldilocks bit of a hack, card swapping, but that would do the trick

Comment: *Cross-compiling* was probably a bit of a hack originally, Iol.

Comment: I’m a bit dyed in the wool big Unix box type to be so cunning 

Comment: @Nick ARM has PAE mode so the kernel could handle the full 8GB in 32bit mode. I'm actually not sure if it does make use of that. Problem remains that each process only gets 4GB max so gcc is limited to that.

Comment: @Nick gcc can run the compiler and assembler in parallel (using the `-pipe` option) or dump the compiler output into a tempfile and then assemble it. Make sure you use the later and /tmp isn't a tempfs if memory is a problem.